# How can I represent CRUD operations in use case diagram?

Tags: uml, software-design, use-case

In an usecase diagram, this is my situation:

Admin (Actor) can:

- View User
- Create User
- Update User
- Delete Us

Searching on web I see that the best way to represent CRUD operations in UCD is doing just a UC "Manage Users", but in this way i have problems with the detailed textual description (Cockburn Template).

For example:

I have to specify all the extension points for "Create User" mask (Required fields, if the user has been created yet, etc..)

The same for Update, and Delete user.

My question now, is this the right way to proceed?

Do I have to specify all the operations, one by one, in the UC "Manage user"?

Sorry for bad English, I hope to have been clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generalization between use cases. So View User, Create User, ... can point to Manage Users. This lets you specify all aspects pertaining to all CRUD operations (like e.g. your actor) at the general use case, and the specific aspects at each special use case. E.g. in most applications, viewing an entity is permitted for more actors than modifying them.

Source: The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual 2nd Edition, where on p 370 they define: *A generalization relationship is a directed relationship between two classifiers of the same kind, such as classes, use cases, ...*, and on p 695, figure B-13 the graphical notation for this is shown.